# What is meant by compensating the Hall Voltage?

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductor-physics, hall-effect

We're doing an experiment to measure the Hall Voltage as functions of current and magnetic field, and we're meant to Compensate the Hall Voltage for $B=0T$. What does this mean, and why do we do it?

Answer (score 0):

The line joining the two electrodes used to measure the Hall voltage needs to be at right angles to the direction of flow of electric current.

If this is not so there will be a voltage across the electrodes even when there is no magnetic field because the electrodes are now measuring the voltage drop due to the specimen under test having a resistance.

[image]

To compensate for any offset a potentiometer (shown at the right of the image)  is used to set the Hall voltage reading to zero when the magnetic field is zero.